# Mono<Mono<Object>> how to subscribe

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to create following chain:

```
Mono<Object1> oneMono = Mono.just("1");
Mono<Object2> twoMono = Mono.just("2");

Mono<Mono<Object5>> resultMono = Mono.zip(oneMono, twoMono, (one, two) -> { 

    Mono<Object3> threeMono = Mono.just("3");
    Mono<Object4> fourMono = Mono.just("4");

    return Mono.zip(threeMono, fourMono, (three, four) -> {
        return "5";
    }
}) // get just Mono<Object5> here?

resultMono.subscribe(mono -> { 
    mono.subscribe();  // ugly double subscribe() !!
});
```

As a result I need to get 5. But before execute 1, 2 and 3, 4.

The code works fine but I would like get out

from  `Mono<Mono<Object5>>` and `double subscribe`

to `Mono<Object5>` and `single subscribe`.

is there an analog flatMap for Zip?

Comment: The values emitted by the Monos are not used, so why do you want to zip them? FWIW you can use the version of `zip` without a combinator and move the code inside a `flatMap`. If you don't need the values you can use `when`. If you don't give us an example that resembles your real use case it's hard to say what's best.

Comment: that is right. thank you. I used the answer below, it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already have it. You just need to use flatMap:

```
Mono<String> oneMono = Mono.just("1");
Mono<String> twoMono = Mono.just("2");

Mono.zip(oneMono, twoMono, (one, two) -> {
    Mono<String> threeMono = Mono.just("3");
    Mono<String> fourMono = Mono.just("4");

    return Mono.zip(threeMono, fourMono, (three, four) -> {
        return "5";
    });
})
.flatMap(stringMono -> stringMono)
.doOnNext(System.out::println)
.subscribe();
```